# intval($id) not matching id in database

Tags: php, mysqli

My update query is not working with my variable $id BUT does work when I use the literal number 29, for example.  I have var_dumped $id and I get INT(29).  Has something changed recently because I copied code that has worked in the past.

```
$id = (ISSET($_GET['id'])) ? intval($_GET['id']):0;//prevents sql inject
var_dump($id);
```

My query that works is the following:

```
$sqlUpdate = $db->query("UPDATE sites SET site_name='$site_name',population='$population' WHERE id=29");
```

This query doesn't work:

```
$sqlUpdate = $db->query("UPDATE sites SET site_name='$site_name',population='$population' WHERE id=$id");
```

Comment: How are you preventing SQL injections with your strings? Output the query with the variable and be sure it is as expected.

Comment: I am using mysqli_real_escape_string to prevent SQL injection of my other variables.  Not sure what you mean by output but I have done a var_dump of all variables and the query returns TRUE.  It seems that intval($id) ends up NOT being the same as what is stored in the id field

Comment: Store `"UPDATE sites SET site_name='$site_name',population='$population' WHERE id=$id"` in a variable then output that prior to execution. Using parameterized queries would be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue/answer.  I used `<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">` within my form because the code to process my form posts resides within the same file.  Upon hitting 'UPDATE' I noticed in the address bar that the filename was correct but it dropped the GET variable for a brief moment.  At this time, the following code ran again...

```
$id = (ISSET($_GET['id'])) ? intval($_GET['id']):0;
$id = protect($db,$id);
```

and my variable $id was changed from the correct GET value to 0, thus preventing my code from updating the correct record.  I changed my code to the following:

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

and everything update perfectly.  If anyone cares to explain WHY this happened I would greatly appreciate it.